# Angular 2 RC4 New Router Warning Message

Tags: angular, router

I see this warning message on the console. I'm using the new angular 2 router. What am I missing or I have to do to fix this warning?

```
'DashboardComponent' not found in precompile array.
To ensure all components referred to by the RouterConfig are compiled, you must add 'DashboardComponent' to the 'precompile' array of your application component.
This will be required in a future release of the router.
```

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144547/in-angular2-rc4-how-do-i-add-components-to-the-precompile-array

Answer (score 10):

Upgrading to router 3 beta 2 removed the warning for me

Comment: To upgrade the router to 3.0.0-beta.2, look in package.json for "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1" and change it to "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2". Then run npm install and npm start.

Comment: This did not fix it for me...no idea why.  I made sure it did update to beta 2 as well.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Great worked for me! By the way, tried to add it to precompile in beta.1 at appComponent level, but it seems not help.